# What does DUnit2's CallerAddr function do, and how do I convert it to 64 bits?

Tags: delphi, assembly, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to get DUnit2 working under 64 bits, but I am stumped to what this method does, let alone how to convert it to 64 bits. Pure Pascal would better, but since it refers to the stack (ebp), it might not be possible.

```
function CallerAddr: Pointer; assembler;
const
  CallerIP = $4;
asm
   mov   eax, ebp
   call  IsBadPointer
   test  eax,eax
   jne   @@Error

   mov   eax, [ebp].CallerIP
   sub   eax, 5   // 5 bytes for call

   push  eax
   call  IsBadPointer
   test  eax,eax
   pop   eax
   je    @@Finish

@@Error:
   xor eax, eax
@@Finish:
end;
```

Comment: To give a bit of explanation to those not intimately familiar with the Delphi runtime: The above is 32bit x86 assembler for the "usual" situation that code uses framepointers; due to the function epilogue `push EBP; mov ESP, EBP` the result is that `[ EBP + 4 ]` is always the return address (as written by the `CALL` used to enter a function). Framepointers are optional on 64bit, often optimized out, so simply replacing `[ EBP + 4 ]` with `[ RBP + 8 ]` isn't ok. The Delphi runtime has `RtlCaptureStackBacktrace()` (just like e.g. Linux glibc has `backtrace()`) as "abstracted" solution for this.

Comment: @frankh Aren't frame pointers optional on x86 also? Also this has nothing to do with Delphi runtime. RtlCaptureStackBacktrace is a Windows API.

Comment: @David Hefferman: The code shown by the original poster cannot/will not work on 32bit if framepointers are optimized out. Hence my assumption had to be that (as it supposedly works for Delphi-compiled code) they're _not_ optional (in 32bit Delphi). Ack on `RtlCaptureStackBacktrace()` - missed the `kernel32.dll` below. Was largely posting this comment because the accepted answer is a "magic" one and noone unfamiliar with this will be able to learn from it ...

Comment: @Frank There's no need to assume anything. The documentation makes it clear that stack frames are optional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function RtlCaptureStackBackTrace(FramesToSkip: ULONG; FramesToCapture: ULONG; 
  out BackTrace: Pointer; BackTraceHash: PULONG): USHORT; stdcall; 
  external 'kernel32.dll' name 'RtlCaptureStackBackTrace' delayed;

function CallerAddr: Pointer;
begin
  // Skip 2 Frames, one for the return of CallerAddr and one for the
  // return of RtlCaptureStackBackTrace
  if RtlCaptureStackBackTrace(2, 1, Result, nil) > 0 then
  begin
    if not IsBadPointer(Result) then
      Result := Pointer(NativeInt(Result) - 5)
    else
      Result := nil;
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function CallerAddr: Pointer; assembler;
    const
      CallerIP = $4;
    asm
       mov   rax, rcx ;For int.. XMM0 for float
       call  IsBadPointer
       test  rax,rax
       jne   @@Error

       mov   rax, [rcx].CallerIP
       sub   rax, 5   // 5 bytes for call

       push  rax
       call  IsBadPointer
       test  rax,rax
       pop   rax
       je    @@Finish

    @@Error:
       xor rax, rax
    @@Finish:
    end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but it doesn't work. I get the following access violation when the function exits.
 
exception class $C0000005 with message 'c0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION'.

Comment: −1 for entirely missing the point. This is a literal conversion of the original code — it uses 64-bit registers instead of 32-bit registers — so I can't strictly call it a *wrong* answer. However, it's an eminently *unhelpful* answer because it shows no effort to understand the purpose of the original code or ensure that this function accomplishes the same goal as the original.